# How to solve the ODE $\ddot{x}=\frac{c}{x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the following ODE? $$\ddot{x}=\frac{c}{x}$$

I have no idea how to solve it since it is not linear. Is there a way of separation or something like that?

Comment: What is the meaning of the double dots on the $x$ ?

Comment: @imranfat: If $x=f(t)$ then $\ddot{x}=\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}$.

Comment: @imranfat Overdots are commonly used in physics and engineering to denote time derivatives, i.e., $\ddot{x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 x}{\mathrm{d}t^2}$. The solutions of this ODE appear to be non-elementary. *Mathematica* gives an answer in terms of the inverse error function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is easier if you write it as a system of first order differential equations. like this $$\frac{dx}{dt} = y, \frac{dy}{dt} = \frac{c}{x}.$$ you can turn this into $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{c}{xy} $$ which can be separated as $$y\, dy =  \frac{c}{x}$$

you can take it from there.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Multiply both sides by $\dot x$ and integrate over $t$ on both sides.

Hint 2: $\dot x dt = dx$

Answer (score 3):

$\textbf{hint}$
$$
\ddot{x} = \dot{x}\dfrac{d}{dx}\dot{x} = \dfrac{d}{dx}\frac{\dot{x}^2}{2} = \frac{c}{x}
$$

Given that 
$$
\dfrac{d}{dt} =\dfrac{dx}{dt}\frac{d}{dx} = \dot{x}\dfrac{d}{dx}\tag{*}
$$
Then
$$
\ddot{x} = \dfrac{d}{dt}\dot{x} 
$$
Take eq(*) and put in the above
$$
\ddot{x} = \dot{x}\dfrac{d}{dx}\dot{x} 
$$

Comment: What do you mean by $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$ here? I was under the impression that $x$ was the independent variable.

Comment: @davidzhang  $$\dfrac{dx}{dt}\frac{d}{dx} = \dfrac{d}{dt}$$

Comment: Can you explain how the first equality is derived?

Comment: @martinr does that answer your question? I am not sure if it is because you think I have done it wrong? Or you are not sure about the method..though your profile seems it is the former rather than the later.

Comment: I was confused because you take the derivative of a function $x(t)$ with respect to $x$. But I see now that it works (and gives the same result as multiplying the equation by $\dot{x}$ and integrating with respect to $t$).

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\frac{c}{x}$$
$$2\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{2c}{x}\frac{dx}{dt}=$$
$$\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2=2c\ln(x)+C_1$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\pm \sqrt{2c\ln(x)+C_1}$$
$$dt=\pm\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2c\ln(x)+C_1}}$$
$$t=\pm\int{\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2c\ln(x)+C_1}}+C_2}$$
The closed form of this integral involves special function of the erf kind. $x(t)$ is the inverse function.